# Remote compression of files using S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, compression

Does Anyone know if it is possible to compress files directly on S3 without downloading to disk (using EC2), or creating a pipe (using [archiver](https://dev.to/lineup-ninja/zip-files-on-s3-with-aws-lambda-and-node-1nm1))?

Comment: no, it's not possible, you can check [s3-browser] https://s3browser.com/compression-encryption.aspx if it helps your usecase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to manipulate the contents of files 'within' Amazon S3.

The compression would need to be done with some "compute", such as:

- An AWS Lambda function (memory and disk limits apply)
- Code running on an Amazon EC2 instance
- Code running anywhere on the Internet (but Data Transfer charges would apply)

This would involve downloading the objects from S3, compressing them, then uploading the result.